# Proper way of updating a whole table in Redshift, drop table + create table vs. truncate + insert into table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Currently I have many tables for which I have to update the information they hold, sometimes on a daily or weekly basis. So far, I've been doing this by a combination of `DROP TABLE IF EXIST some_schema.some_table_name;` followed by `CREATE TABLE some_schema.some_table_name AS ( SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...);` and I would like to know what is the "best-practice" or proper way of doing so.

I've read that `INSERT` operations in Redshift are quite expensive, so I've been avoiding its usage, but maybe the use of `TRUNCATE` with `INSERT` is better than dropping and creating.

How can I confirm which option is better?

I've seen [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html) article from Redshift docs, but I'm not sure if it is the best option, since I could have not only to remove records, but keeping and inserting as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your desire is to completely erase a table and replace the data then the general pattern you are following in fine.  However, there are a few things you should be doing to make things safer / better.

There are 3 patterns to do this and one is clearly the lowest performance.  These are Delete/Insert, Truncate/Insert, and Drop/Insert.  Of these Delete/Create/Insert is NOT what you want to do from a performance point of view.  This process invalidates all the rows in the table (not delete them) and adds new valid rows.  This doubles the size of the table, wasting space, and needs to be vacuumed.  The only upside of this approach is that it doesn't have the downsides of the other approaches but this only matters in certain situations.  Go down this approach only if you have to.

Truncate/Insert is fast and maintains the same table id as the original table.  Because truncate operates on the blocks of the table (unlinking them) it is fast but there is some small overhead in managing all the block links.  Since the table definition is unchanged all DDL stays defined and dependent views can keep pointing to the table.  The downside with truncate is that it forces a COMMIT to occur which means that until the table is repopulated with new data other users of the database can see an empty table.  This can lead to incorrect results during these windows. Not good.

Lastly there is Drop/Create/Insert.  This approach is marginally (very slightly and only for large tables) faster than truncate in the ideal case.  It just throws away the old blocks.  There is some additional cost to setting up the new table (of the same name) so truncate and drop are about the same speed unless the table is large.  Since Drop can be inside of a transaction block the empty table won't be seen by third parties (if done correctly).  The downside with this approach is that the old table and new table are entirely different tables (different oids) - they just happen to have the same name.  This means that any dependent (regular) views will need to be dropped and recreated as well.  Also since this table is "going away" the commit of the transaction cannot complete until all uses of the table are complete.  This becomes a large problem when someone leaves a transaction open in their bench and goes home for the night.  Since the tables needs to be recreated your process needs to know the complete and correct DDL for the table.

Hopefully this gives you some idea of when to use these different approaches.  Two things I see that could be better in your current code - 1) You are not using a transaction block (as far as I can tell) so there is a window when others will see that the tables doesn't exists or is empty.  This may or may not be important to you but be aware. 2) "Create table As" doesn't define the DDL of the table in performant structure (and possibly incorrectly).  You should always specify your permanent tables fully.  Sort and Dist keys matter as do varchar lengths, data types etc.  This is a time bomb waiting to go off.

Per request for an example of drop/create/insert:

As I mentioned there are lock dependency issues that can arise with this method so I like to use a "swap & drop" approach to this path.  This makes the new information visible to users at the "swap" so even if the "drop" gets blocks things get published on time.  This doesn't remove the lock risk as a lock can still prevent the process (session) from completing, it just makes it so that the new data is visible (published) while you hunt down the offender.

(Please note that for transactions to execute properly you need to be sure that extra COMMITs are not being inserted into the process.  This can happen with benches that are configured in "autocommit" mode.)

```
Create table new_table ( ... ) ...;  -- make the new table but with a different name (and unique from other tables) than the existing table
Insert into new_table ... ; -- put the desired data into the new table
Analyze new_table;  -- to ensure metadata is up to date
Begin; -- start transaction
Alter table perm_table rename to old_table; -- rename existing table
Alter table new_table rename to perm_table; -- complete the swap
Commit; -- publish the new data for all to see but transactions still using the original data can keep doing so
Drop table old_table;  -- remove the old data to free up space
Commit;
```

This process is just one example. Sometimes you want to keep the old versions of the table around for a while (history / error recovery) so you will date stamp the old data and have a separate process to free up the space.  This also helps with stray locks clogging up the works - only the clean up process gets stalled.  You can also have the recreation of views in the process so that these are updated in the same transaction. And so on.

Comment: Thanks Bill, this is the kind of explanation I was looking for. A few comments about your answer, just in case these clarifies some needs. I don't desire is to completely erase a table and replace the data, in fact, I'm always recreating the table with the same structure of the one I've just dropped, what I'm really looking to achieve is to "forget" about the data they have, and place again, into the table, the "current" or the most-up-to-date data, in the most efficient or "best-practice" way. Also I would like to know what do I have to do in order to create the transaction block correctly?

Comment: About the `CREATE TABLE ... AS`, I'm creating the tables this way because I thought that the DDL definitions will be inherited from the table I'm doing the `SELECT` exactly what I'm currently doing is something like `CREATE TABLE some_schema.some_table_name DISTKEY(colum_x) SORTKEY(column_x) AS (` but, again, I don't know if it is the "right" way, nor how to know it.

Comment: I think my "erase and replace" and your "forget and place again" are, to the database, the same thing.  I think you are speaking from the data's point of view but please let me know if I'm missing a specific database end-state difference.  You want to "empty the table and refill it".  The "best way" is dependent on what the requirements are for the database.  I have no good understanding of your constraints which is why I laid out the differences / pros / cons.  I'll add an example of how I have done drop/insert but it may not be ideal for you (will show the transaction).

Comment: DDL definition is not inherited from the source table though some information can be in cases.  If the select is "simple" then the dist and sort keys will be inherited but otherwise will be inferred from the query plan.  Having the dist and sort keys explicit in the CTAS is good and prevents some issues.  Column types will be defined by the query plan so again will be the source table definition for "simple" selects.  Column encoding are never preserved and will be hard coded based on data type/other DDL info.   Constraints are never inherited.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with CTAS, just be aware what it does and doesn't do.  The concern I raised is around supporting code base over the long-term.  Having implicit DDL coming from select statements that may change in the future can create hard to find problem down the road.  If you really just want to make the table with the same definition as another existing table I'd suggest CREATE TABLE LIKE.  However, this can create another type of hard to find dependency.  I prefer to have all my table DDL in a checked-in repository and have my code use explicit DDL definitions pulled from this repo.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Absolutely, your "erase and replace" and my "forget and place again" are the same thing. Right now I have no major constraints (I guess) since I'm not currently using views and this tables are not used to feed dynamic real-time websites and such. Are used to fill weekly reports (mainly)

Comment: Not having views and no one else looking at the tables definitely helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to use the Update command. I understand that drooping a table is a risky move, as you might loose all of your data from your database.

```
Update some_table_name s set
   s.Id="whatever you want to update",
   s.Name="whatever you want to update",
   s.LastName="whatever you want to update",
   s.OtherTableColumn="whatever you want to update"
From
   some_table_name s
```

In above code I assumed your table had for columns (1-Id, 2-Name, 3-LastName, 4-OtherTableColumn). If you have more or less columns then I would adjust accordingly.

I would also write a update procedure for this (and each table) so if you need to update somewhat frequently you just use the procedure; I think its quicker. Below would be my procedure:

```
Create Proc sp_UpdateSome_table_name
   @Id int,
   @name nvarchar(255),
   @lastname nvarchar(255),
   @OtherTableColumn int
AS
BEGIN
Update s some_table_name
       
   s.Name="whatever you want to update",
   s.LastName="whatever you want to update",
   s.OtherTableColumn="whatever you want to update"
From
   some_table_name s
Where
   s.Id=@Id
END
```

You want to make sure that each column in your table is defined with correct data type in the procedure. For example I assumed above that @Id was int, Name was nvarchar(255) etc. If you want to allow yourself not to enter any data (allowing null) in certain table columns when updating then after the data type you can write Null; for example if you write @Id int Null, then you can update is as null; but if you are not sure what this is, simply ignore this sentence for now.

Once you assured above paragraph is good (data types are correct), then select the entire procedure and then execute (F5). This will store this procedure.

Then I will write the procedure every time you want to update your table shown as below:

```
Exec sp_UpdateSome_table_name 1,John,Smith,77
```

If you highlight the above command and execute (f5) it then it will update the table which has Id=1 and it will make the name John, last name Smith and the other column 77 from whatever it was before. If there is no data in the table with Id=1 then you can execute.

Keep in mind the last rows of the codes might not have a comma. The above codes are written correctly, just pointing it out as you might put a comma out of habit.